# How to share a value with two different variables in Terraform tfvars?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I've got a few months in on Terraform and finally trying to make a module. I have a `.tfvars` file declaring a CIDR mask for an AWS vpc like this:

```
my_cidr = "10.10.10.0/24"
```

I want to reference `my_cidr` in several places within the project. For instance, farther down in the `.tvfars` itself:

```
efs_ingress = [
  {
    description       = "Allowed EFS ingress sources"
    from_port         = 2049
    to_port           = 2049
    protocol          = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks       = [var.my_cidr] # ideally, this would work :/
    ipv6_cidr_blocks  = null
    prefix_list_ids   = []
    security_groups   = []
    self              = false
  }
]
```

The docs I've read so far say it's not possible to reference a variable in `.tfvars` but duplicating hard-coded values everywhere is super messy. Is there a better solution?

Comment: It's not possible for a variable to reference other variables, unless it's local.

Comment: no way to declare locals in `.tfvars`? I get `Error: Unexpected "locals" block`

Comment: Local variables should be in any other `.tf` file, but usually it's defined in its own, `locals.tf` file. It cannot be used in any type of `.tfvars` file.

Comment: Also the `cidr` should probably be defined within the `efs_ingress` anyway, and that would resolve this issue and clean up the variable declarations.

Comment: I think that will work. Any resources or modules can reference the CIDR for the VPC as `var.efs_ingress.cidr_blocks` instead of the way I was planning: eg:`var.my_cidr`.

Answer (score 0):

The intended way to address a use-case like this is to separate the input variables.

You can use Local variables for **efs_ingress** declaration like below for **name** variable

```
locals {
  name = "${var.firstname} {$var.firstname}"
}
```

Comment: Please read the question. The user wants to refer variable in tfvars file which is impossible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).